# Mouseenter item card

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, card

Please help with the code! I need to hover the mouse over the button with the cart, it added a class and svg class, and the button with favorites, also added a class.
And Vice versa-hovering the mouse over your favorites, the button with the cart is hidden

```js
$('.item-block__button-cart').mouseenter

function() {
  $(this).addClass('item-block__button-cart--active');
  $(this).find("svg").addClass("active-svg");
  $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").addClass("item-block__button-favorite--deactive");
}
);

$('.item-block__button-cart').mouseleave

function() {
  $(this).removeClass('item-block__button-cart--active');
  $(this).find("svg").removeClass("active-svg");
  $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").removeClass("item-block__button-favorite--deactive");

}
);

$('.item-block__button-favorite').mouseenter

function() {
  $(this).addClass('item-block__button-favorite--active');
  $(this).find("svg").addClass("active-svg");
  $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").addClass("item-block__button-cart--deactive");
}
);

$('.item-block__button-favorite').mouseleave

function() {
  $(this).removeClass('item-block__button-favorite--active');
  $(this).find("svg").removeClass("active-svg");
  $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").removeClass("item-block__button-cart--deactive");

}
);
```

```css
.item-block__buttons {
  border-top: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 96%, .75);
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  z-index: 2;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .75);
  overflow: hidden
}

.item-block:hover .catalog__items-item-slider .carousel__arrow--detail,
.item-block:hover .item-block__buttons {
  opacity: 1
}

.item-block__button {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .1s;
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s
}

.item-block__button-cart--deactive,
.item-block__button-favorite--deactive {
  display: none
}

.item-block__button-cart--active,
.item-block__button-favorite--active {
  width: 100%
}

.item-block__button-favorite {
  border-right: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 96%, .7)
}

.item-block__button-favorite--active {
  border: none
}

.item-block__button svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 75px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  fill: #4c4b5b;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, -webkit-transform .2s
}

.item-block__button i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #b6b8ba;
  margin-top: -9px;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center
}

.item-block__button-cart svg {
  left: auto;
  right: 80px
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button svg {
  left: 175px
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-cart svg {
  left: auto;
  right: 175px
}

.item-block__button-cart--added svg.active-svg {
  right: 160px
}

.item-block__button-cart--active svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-135px, -50%);
  transform: translate(-135px, -50%)
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-cart--active svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-240px, -50%);
  transform: translate(-240px, -50%)
}

.item-block__button-favorite--active svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(30px, -50%);
  transform: translate(30px, -50%)
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-favorite--active svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(130px, -50%);
  transform: translate(130px, -50%)
}

.item-block__button a.addet-to-basket-link,
.item-block__button span {
  color: #4c4b5b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 115px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  letter-spacing: 1.05px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .1s;
  transition: transform .2s, opacity .1s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  opacity: 0
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button span {
  left: 215px
}

.item-block__button-cart span {
  left: auto;
  right: -30px;
  color: #ff2438
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-cart span {
  left: auto;
  right: 65px
}

.item-block__button-cart--added span {
  right: -80px
}

.item-block__button-cart--active span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-135px);
  transform: translateX(-135px)
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-cart--active span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-240px);
  transform: translateX(-240px)
}

.item-block__button-favorite--added span {
  left: 35px
}

.item-block__button-favorite--active.item-block__button-favorite--added svg {
  left: 0
}

.item-block__button-favorite--active span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  transform: translateX(30px)
}

.item-block--big .item-block__button-favorite--active span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(130px);
  transform: translateX(130px)
}

.item-block__button-favorite svg {
  width: 22px;
  fill: #4c4b5b;
  height: 18px
}

.item-block__button-cart svg {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  fill: #ff2438
}
```

```html
<span class="item-block__buttons">
        <span class="js-add-to-favorite item-block__button item-block__button-favorite" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" onclick="return $.addFavorite('/shop/favorite/', {@id}, this)">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z"></path></svg>
                            <span>В избранное</span>
</span>
<span class="js-add-to-basket js-add-to-basket-list item-block__button item-block__button-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#added2basket" data-placement="top" onclick="return $.bootstrapAddIntoCart('/shop/cart/', {@id}, 1)">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><circle cx="10" cy="20.5" r="1"/><circle cx="18" cy="20.5" r="1"/><path d="M2.5 2.5h3l2.7 12.4a2 2 0 0 0 2 1.6h7.7a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.6l1.6-8.4H7.1"/></svg>
                            <span>В корзину</span>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: There is no issue in your code and is working as expected in the question. Can you check your `console` for errors ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! There are no errors in the console, but the code doesn't work. The class is assigned to span inside span, and for some reason it is assigned to svg, although svg has its own class specified.  http://cp38007.tmweb.ru/shop/kollekczii/39262ED1-F578-B601-7DBE-DC0C1075D8DC/

Comment: The cache was updated and now there is an error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Answer (score 0):

This code work!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.item-block__button-cart').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('item-block__button-cart--active');
    $(this).find("svg").addClass("active-svg");
    $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").addClass("item-block__button-favorite--deactive");
  });

  $('.item-block__button-cart').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('item-block__button-cart--active');
    $(this).find("svg").removeClass("active-svg");
    $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").removeClass("item-block__button-favorite--deactive");

  });

  $('.item-block__button-favorite').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('item-block__button-favorite--active');
    $(this).find("svg").addClass("active-svg");
    $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").addClass("item-block__button-cart--deactive");
  });

  $('.item-block__button-favorite').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('item-block__button-favorite--active');
    $(this).find("svg").removeClass("active-svg");
    $(this).siblings(".item-block__button").removeClass("item-block__button-cart--deactive");
  });

});
```